# How to select only the selected checkboxes from multiple checkboxes when the button is pressed in kivymd?

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

How can I select only the selected checkboxes from the list of the checkboxes in kivymd? I want to print only the selected checkbox when the "Selected" button is pressed and not all the checkboxes.

Note: I do not use the .kv file and kv string both

The whole source code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.card import MDCard
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.selectioncontrol import MDCheckbox
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
from kivymd.uix.boxlayout import MDBoxLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.metrics import dp
from kivymd.uix.fitimage import FitImage
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton
from kivymd.uix.behaviors import RoundedRectangularElevationBehavior
class mdcard_rahul(MDCard,RoundedRectangularElevationBehavior):
    pass

class Item_Menu(MDBoxLayout):
    list_of_information={"checkbox":[],"label":[],"Quantity":[]}
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Item_Menu,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size_hint=(1,0.9)
        self.pos_hint={"top":1}
        self.orientation="vertical"
        scrollbarwin=ScrollView()
        content_box=BoxLayout(orientation='vertical',padding=dp(8),spacing=dp(8),size_hint=(1,None))
        content_box.bind(minimum_height=content_box.setter('height'))
        for i in range(0,50):
            Template_card= mdcard_rahul(
                size_hint_y=None,
                size_hint_x=.960,
                height = dp(100),
                padding = dp(4),
                pos_hint={'center_y': .5, 'center_x': .490},
                radius = [20,],
                elevation = 4,

            )
            checkbox=MDCheckbox(
                size_hint=(None, None),
                size= (dp(48),dp(48)),
                pos_hint={'center_y': .5}
            )
            self.list_of_information["checkbox"].append(checkbox)
            image_box=MDBoxLayout(adaptive_size=True)
            image=FitImage(
                source="D:/Study/Python/Kivy/images/2.jpg",
                size_hint= (None, None),
                height=dp(80),
                width=dp(130),
                radius=[12,],
                pos_hint={'center_y':0.5}

            )
            image_box.add_widget(image)
            text_box=MDBoxLayout(orientation="vertical",adaptive_height=True,pos_hint={'center_y':0.5},padding=[12,0,0,0])
            item_name=MDLabel(text=f"item{i+1}",font_style="H5",size_hint=(1,None),bold=True,theme_text_color="Primary")
            item_name.bind(texture_size=item_name.setter('size'))
            self.list_of_information["label"].append(item_name)
            price=MDLabel(text=u"Price: \u20B910/per",font_style="Subtitle1",size_hint=(1,None),bold=True,theme_text_color="Hint")
            price.bind(texture_size=price.setter('size'))
            quantitybox=MDBoxLayout(orientation='vertical',adaptive_height=True,size_hint_x=0.2,pos_hint = {'center_y': .5,'center_x':0.5})
            quantityfield=MDTextField(
                hint_text= "Quantity",
                mode= "rectangle",
                size_hint=(None,None),
                width=dp(80),
                height= dp(40),
                padding=[0,0,15,0]
            )
            self.list_of_information["Quantity"].append(quantityfield)
            quantitybox.add_widget(quantityfield)
            Template_card.add_widget(checkbox)
            Template_card.add_widget(image_box)
            Template_card.add_widget(text_box)
            text_box.add_widget(item_name)
            text_box.add_widget(price)
            Template_card.add_widget(quantitybox)
            content_box.add_widget(Template_card)
        scrollbarwin.add_widget(content_box)
        buttonbox=MDBoxLayout(orientation="vertical",pos_hint={"top":0.1},adaptive_height=True)
        button=MDRaisedButton(text="Selected!!!",size_hint=(1,0.2))
        button.bind(on_release=lambda x:self.Selected_checkbox)
        buttonbox.add_widget(button)
        self.add_widget(scrollbarwin)
        self.add_widget(buttonbox)
    def Selected_checkbox(self):
        Selected=[item for item in Item_Menu.list_of_information['checkbox'] if item.active]
        print(Selected)

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style="Dark"
        return Item_Menu()

MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to change:

```
    button.bind(on_release=lambda x:self.Selected_checkbox)
```

to:

```
    button.bind(on_release=lambda x:self.Selected_checkbox())
```

Note the parens added. It is confusing in python, kivy, and kv lang as to when parens should be included and when they should not be.